# How does one create a "file handler" in iOS, that lets you open a URL in your app if you long press on it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-safari

For example, if you open a PDF in Safari, you have the option to open in iBooks - I believe a number of apps have this ability.

How does one "register" the ability of your app to handle such files, and is it possible so that by "long pressing" a link in Safari, you can get the option to open the URL in your app instead of in Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

look at the documentation on "Registering the File Types Your App Supports"

here is a link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you are going to want to take a look at [Registering Your Support of File Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1) to add your app to the system list of apps that can open specific document types. That is handled by the system.

For the second part, I could be mistaken, but I don't believe you will be able to get that "long press" functionality as it would require changing Safari. If you control the content of the web page however, you could add a [Custom URL Scheme](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html) to your app which would allow you to launch it from a web page.